# Google VR Unity Divider, Settings and Back button hiding in v0.9

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-vr

Does anyone know how to disable the Divider, settings and back button in the latest google vr sdk for unity?

I've tried setting NativeUILayerSupported to false and putting a return in the legacy DrawUILayer but it still shows.

It appears that the older ways of doing it are now fully deprecated.

Comment: "It appears that the older ways of doing it are now fully deprecated" What is the older way of doing it?

Comment: Previous versions of the SDK just had a checkbox (maybe dropdown) on the Cardboard camera prefab for whether or not to show the back button. You can still find the older versions of the SDK by browsing tags in the github repo.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS try to change following:
In Unity, Plugins/iOS/CardboardAppController.mm ->

```
@implementation CardboardAppController

- (UnityView *)createUnityView {
  UnityRegisterViewControllerListener(self);
  UnityRegisterAudioPlugin(UnityGetAudioEffectDefinitions);
  UnityView* unity_view = [super createUnityView];
  //createUiLayer(self, (UIView *)unity_view); <- comment this line
  return unity_view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the settings on your **Cardboard** script under **UI Layer Settings** to false.

Do this from the interface and not from code.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Google VR SDK for Android not the Google VR Unity and this is my solution:

In android, the deprecated method to hide two buttons is

```
// called by VrView
setSettingsButtonEnabled(false);
```

Since now can't use it, so just find this two buttons and hide it myself:

```
findViewById(R.id.ui_back_button).setVisibility(GONE);
findViewById(R.id.ui_settings_button).setVisibility(GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

@PerryHart i was stuck in same problem while using Google VR SDK. Problem is in latest versions of GVR SDK there is no interfacing to disable buttons and other UI Layers. But Google VR SDK 0.8 and less then 0.8 gives interface through which you can do it easily.

[image]

To disable these layers from code is quiet complex and i lost my 2 weeks to do this stuff through code in version GVR 1.xx.

You can download  [Google VR SDK 0.8.1 from here.](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/releases/tag/v0.8.1)

Answer (score -1):

My Scenario :

- Gvr-Ar App with Gvr for just The Gyroscope (Gvr Eyes aint Rendering a thing, using own Cameras)
- Commented the Whole Post Renderer Class ( wich also means i dont have lens disortion calculated, and can use the full screen without the lens shape on the cameras)

What worked for me ( using gvr 1.3 ) :

go into the AndroidDevice.cs Script and comment the Following Lines marked with some ###

```
// Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_HAS_GOOGLEVR

using UnityEngine;

/// @cond
namespace Gvr.Internal {
  public class AndroidDevice : GvrDevice {
  //  private const string ActivityListenerClass =                    ######
  //      "com.google.vr.platform.unity.UnityVrActivityListener";     ######

    private static AndroidJavaObject activityListener;

    public override void Init() {
      SetApplicationState();
      base.Init();
      ConnectToActivity();
    }

    protected override void ConnectToActivity() {
      base.ConnectToActivity();
      if (androidActivity != null && activityListener == null) {
  //      activityListener = Create(ActivityListenerClass);            #####
      }
    }

    public override void SetVRModeEnabled(bool enabled) {
      CallObjectMethod(activityListener, "setVRModeEnabled", enabled);
    }

    public override void ShowSettingsDialog() {
   //   CallObjectMethod(activityListener, "launchConfigureActivity"); #####
    }

    public override void OnPause(bool pause) {
      base.OnPause(pause);
      CallObjectMethod(activityListener, "onPause", pause);
    }

    private void SetApplicationState() {
      if (activityListener == null) {
     //   using (var listenerClass = GetClass(ActivityListenerClass)) {  ###
    //      CallStaticMethod(listenerClass, "setUnityApplicationState"); ###
   //     }                                                            #####
      }
    }
  }
}
/// @endcond

#endif  // UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_HAS_GOOGLEVR
```

I have a wierd Scenario, so if you have the vr mode enabled and this does not work you could try also commenting the body of the SetVRModeEnabled() Function

Comment: actually its just important to comment or delete these : activityListener = Create(ActivityListenerClass);