# GoogleVR : How to disable back button in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, google-vr

The GVrViewer provide several post-render GUI, including **back button** and alignment markers.

How to **disable them from Unity** ? Is it a good idea to do it ?

Comment: I have tried to do this as well, especially that back button, but so far have not found a way. This question is a duplicate of this other one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433089/google-vr-unity-divider-settings-and-back-button-hiding-in-v0-9

Answer (score 0):

In latest versions of Google VR SDK, interface for rendering these buttons has been removed.
Problem occurs when we try to remove these buttons through code, but these GUI layers are so much integrated with different scripts that it becomes difficult to remove these buttons through script.

Best solution for this problem is use [Google VR 0.8.0](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/releases/tag/v0.8.0), as it provides interface to turn on/off these GUI layers (As shown below).

[image]

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Thanks.