# VrVideoView remove UI

Tags: android, google-vr

I'm trying to display a 3D stereo video in a googlevr app in a clean fashion, without showing the UI. I know about usability guidelines, but the device running the app will be always kept inside a viewer in a sort of demo, so no touch interaction expected.

I'm using a VrVideoView.
So I already got rid of fullscreen button, info button, stereo mode button, google cardboard tutorial screen named "transition view" and touch tracking to move the view.

```
videoWidgetView.setFullscreenButtonEnabled(false);
videoWidgetView.setInfoButtonEnabled(false);
videoWidgetView.setStereoModeButtonEnabled(false);
videoWidgetView.setTransitionViewEnabled(false);
videoWidgetView.setTouchTrackingEnabled(false);
```

I also enabled fullscreen stereo by default.

```
videoWidgetView.setDisplayMode(VrWidgetView.DisplayMode.FULLSCREEN_STEREO);
```

But I can't remove the close button "x" and the option button.

[image: VrVideoView annoying UI]

I think that the "x" is `fullscreenBackButton` of `VrWidgetView`, parent of `VrVideoView`. Which hasn't methods to control its visibility.

**Is there a way to remove those two buttons?

Maybe subclassing and rewriting part of the widget code?

Maybe just a little hack putting a black overlay above those corners?**

---

I've also tried as suggested

```
findViewById(R.id.ui_back_button).setVisibility(GONE);
```

or even

```
findViewById(com.google.vr.widgets.common.R.id.ui_back_button).setVisibility(GONE);
```

without success, they give:
**NullPointerException**: Attempt to invoke virtual method *'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)'* on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this solution works.
It uses field functionality to get `vrUiLayer` which is a private member of **VrWidgetView** which is the parent of **VrVideoView**.

```
Field f;
try {
    f = this.videoWidgetView.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("vrUiLayer");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    UiLayer vrLayer = (UiLayer) f.get(this.videoWidgetView);

    // - here you can directly access to the UiLayer class - //


    // to hide the up-right settings button
    vrLayer.setSettingsButtonEnabled(false);

    //setting listener to null hides the x button
    vrLayer.setBackButtonListener(null);

    // these visibility options are frequently updated when you play videos,
    // so you have to call them often


    // OR


    vrLayer.setEnabled(false); // <- just hide the UI layer


} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Don't forget to import the class

```
import com.google.vr.cardboard.UiLayer
```

Beware that using `vrLayer.setEnabled(false)` hides also the center line, leaving a complete clean vr experience.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this post: [Google VR Unity Divider, Settings and Back button hiding in v0.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433089/google-vr-unity-divider-settings-and-back-button-hiding-in-v0-9/41326026#41326026).

VrVideoView extends [VrWidgetView](https://github.com/wjfsanhe/ddwangjf/blob/master/daydream/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/common/VrWidgetView.java). There you will find a clue on how to disable the settings button in the `updateButtonVisibility()` method: `vrUiLayer.setSettingsButtonEnabled(displayMode == 3)`.

Alternatively try tracing the resource ID of the buttons and do:

```
findViewById(R.id.ui_back_button).setVisibility(GONE);
findViewById(R.id.ui_settings_button).setVisibility(GONE);
```

---

You can also iterate on all resources and try disable one by one:

```
final R.drawable drawableResources = new R.drawable();
final Class<R.drawable> c = R.drawable.class;
final Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();

for (int i = 0, max = fields.length; i < max; i++) {
    final int resourceId;
    try {
        resourceId = fields[i].getInt(drawableResources);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        continue;
    }
    /* make use of resourceId for accessing Drawables here */
}
```

Comment: OK, that seems close, I wish I could access `vrUiLayer`, but its not public so I can't call `this.vrUiLayer.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: By the way the `findViewById().setVisibility()` method gives **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference**

Comment: Sorry, your edit do not works because it lists only views of my app and not the ones from the package **com.google.vr**